# What is the use of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\IdentityInterface in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, email, order-email

```
protected function checkAndSend(Order $order)
{
    $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());
    if (!$this->identityContainer->isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->prepareTemplate($order);

    /** @var SenderBuilder $sender */
    $sender = $this->getSender();

    try {
        $sender->send();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    try {
        $sender->sendCopyTo();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
    }
    return true;
}
```

What is the use of this line of code $this->identityContainer->isEnabled() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

We got Email identity from Store->Config->Sales->Sales Emails. Here we go the data for Identity.